# Why was .NET called .NET?

Tags: .net, terminology

I always wondered why Microsoft chose such a strange, search-engine-unfriendly name for such a great platform. Couldn't they have come up with something better?

Apparently the codename was NGWS:

> Microsoft started development on the
>   .NET Framework in the late 1990s
>   originally under the name of Next
>   Generation Windows Services (NGWS). <sup>[[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions)</sup>

Does anyone know why they chose the name .NET?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

.NET enabled Microsoft's marketing people to emphasise the "Network"-ing aspect of its technologies, and was also a reaction to the marketing blitz by Sun Microsystems in the late 1990s whose theme was "The network is the computer". The term "Dot-Com" was synonymous with the Internet that time, and "Dot-NET" was a play on that term.

I don't think it is a bad name at all, the problem was that Microsoft named so many products with the ".Net" nomenclature like .NET My Services and Microsoft .NET Enterprise Servers where the latter had nothing to do with the Internet. It caused so much confusion. Only later did Microsoft correct things by limiting the .NET name to technologies related to the Managed Runtime Framework.

Comment: remember the .NET Passport? I think that was the most confusing bit for users.

Comment: I remember being very confused by the .NET marketing. It meant everything and nothing. They would have saved a ton of problems if they just said "it is something like Java".

Comment: The .NET name put me off learning it for quite a while it seemed to have no focus as to what it was. I kept focused on Java for a lot longer because of it.

Comment: Maybe this old article will be interesting: Gates: .Net Is 'Architecture For This Decade' InformationWeek 2002 http://bit.ly/dc3Wm6

Answer (score 12):

interNET would be my guess

In the mid\late 90's Microsoft saw the internet as the Future and also felt they where a little late to the game. Thus Explorer being forced on people by being embedded in the OS(Which they are regretting now). Removing competitors such as Java from Windows AND a really over the top name like .NET to indicate there are now a web friendly company....

Comment: I think you mean "In the late 90's"  They kind of flubbed the early and mid 90's.

Comment: And I think you meant Internet Explorer, not Explorer. Explorer is a part of Windows that has nothing to do with web browsers. It is a local machine file browser (the Windows shell showing your C: files icons). But they did embed Internet Explorer into Windows Explorer and that's why they felt they had a case when defending against the notion of removing Internet Explorer from being preinstalled in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I was a dev at Microsoft at the time, and I have no idea whose ass the name .NET was pulled from. Anyone I talked to thought it was a lousy name for all the reasons already enumerated. At least it's pronounceable, unlike NGWS.

Comment: NGWS is perfectly pronounceable! Think the word “penguins”, but without the the “pen” or the “n”—“nguis”!

Comment: @notJim Yeah and it sounds horrible!

Answer (score 5):

The early marketing thrust of .NET was web services. .NET was supposed to make it easy both to write and consume web services. In particular, it was supposed to make it easier to call the web services that Microsoft was going to provide, and that everyone would then use: the ".NET My Services".

Of course, that fell apart very quickly, but the name remained. It was at least better than "COM++" or "ActiveXX".

Comment: +1. I think during very early days even ASP.NET was called ASP+.

Here is an article written in July 2000:- http://archive.devx.com/asp/articles/ck072600/ck072600.asp

Comment: @Ashish: you're right about "ASP+". That's why we have ".ASPX" files.