# What is the full form of .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was .NET called .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628145/why-was-net-called-net)

Hai all,
   What is the full form of .NET and explain why its called so.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by "full form"?

Comment: Please google before asking any question. PLEASE.

Comment: @damovisa he means, what does NET in .NET stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because .COM was overused.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it is Network Enabled Technology :)

Answer (score 0):

Could have borrowed NET from Inter**net** as a marketing gimmick :|